# PM2 start npm -- start error

Tags: node.js, express, npm, pm2

I have been using "npm start" to start up my express server (for my angular 2 cli project) for a couple of weeks and it works fine except it doesn't restart automatically when crashed. Now, to make it restart automatically, I tried to use PM2. Based on my research, it should be as simple as running

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

However, this gives me "stopped" status right away. Doing "pm2 show" leads me to look at the error in npm-error-0.log, and there I see this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mingliu_99\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:83:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { :: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
                                                              ^
```

This is my start script in my package.json file:

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist-prod/server.js"
```

So, what's the problem here?

By the way, when I try with this command

```
pm2 start dist-prod/server.js
```

it seems to be started fine (with green online status). However, the server is not serving, which is probably because the env parameter is missing.

UPDATE:

I found [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2808) and it turns out to be a problem of pm2 on windows 10.

The workaround suggested in the end of that post seems to work fine.

Basically, install node-cmd first, and create a startscript.js:

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd'); 
cmd.run('npm start');
```

and then run

```
pm2 start startscript.js
```

Comment: which version of node.js & pm2 do you use?  `node -v && pm2 -v`

Comment: node v8.6.0 and pm2 2.10.2.

Comment: Does anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the server setup scripts 
Eg. `pm2 start app:name backend scripts`

In this case your scripts is any script.js listening to your server.

To watch and reload instantly use `pm2 start app:name backend` scripts --watch